# Warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast for Map

Tags: java, spring-boot

I found the following exception. How do I resolve that warning?

**Exception:**

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
  Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) obj;
                                                           
  required: Map<String,Object>
  found:    Object
```

**Code:**

```
List<?> results = response.getResults();
for (Object result : results) {
Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) result;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Casting an `Object` to a `Map` will always give you this warning.

The only way to fix it is to have a more specific type than `Object` in the first place.